# Discrete Wavelet Transformation

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I need help for [discrete wavelet transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) source code with MATLAB.
Could I know full discrete wavelet transformation source code with MATLAB that can be used for video processing?

Especially I need code for a [Wyner-Ziv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_source_coding#Wyner-Ziv_Coding_-_Lossy_Distributed_Coding) filter using wavelet transformation with MATLAB.

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend the [MATLAB Wavelet Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/wavelet/) for this application. It is intuitive and easy to use and you can get up and running very quickly on wavelet transforms in general, and the discrete wavelet transform in particular. We have been using it in my group for 1D applications, but much of the toolbox is designed specifically to be used for 2D image processing related tasks.

Comment: I would also highly recommend this toolbox.  We used it quite a bit in my image processing courses, and its pretty simple to use and implement the various wavelets.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the Mathworks-specific MATLAB Wavelet Toolbox, I would also suggest the

- [Rice Wavelet Toolbox](http://dsp.rice.edu/software/rice-wavelet-toolbox),
- Ivan Selesnick's [Wavelet Software](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/WaveletSoftware/), or
- [WaveLab](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~wavelab/) from David Donoho (and colleagues) at Stanford University

I am not too sure about video processing, but all three are good-quality and free.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the book "[Ripples in Mathematics: The Discrete Wavelet
Transform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540416625)" by A. Jensen and  Anders la Cour-Harbo (ISBN:
3-540-41662-5). In fact, a few years ago, I participated in a
course held by one of the authors. The book contains MATLAB
source and chapter 13, starting on page 211, is "Wavelets in
MATLAB".

It also has 2D transform examples (for images). Chapter 6,
"Two Dimensional Transforms", starts with "In this chapter
we will briefly show how the discrete wavelet transform can
applied to two dimensional signals, such as images".

For some examples it uses the free [Uvi_Wave Wavelet
Toolbox](http://www.gts.tsc.uvigo.es/~wavelets/uvi_wave.html) - "... is a set of Wavelet Processing based
functions implemented under ... MATLAB ... includes
Wavelet Transform functions for one or more dimensions...
includes Wavelet Packet Transform (one and two
dimensional)."

Answer (score 0):

You could try a trial version of the [Matlab Wavelet Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/wavelet/).

Or google [dwt matlab](http://www.google.com/search?q=dwt+matlab&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a).